# Python Logging : how to add a custom field to LogRecord, and register a global callback to sets it's value

Tags: python, flask

In a Flask application, I want to add a `user_id` field added to every error log record that gets produced, whenever a `user_id` exists in the `flask.session`.

I came up with the solution below but it's hackish, since it doesn't allow for the format string to drive the formatting of the `user_id`, and since the logging API seems to provides ways to customize logging (`LoggerAdapter`, `logging.makeRecord`, etc...) I figure there has to be a cleaner way.

What would be the "python way" to do it ?

```
class CustomFormatter(Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        from myapp.core import authenticationManager
        user_id = authenticationManager.current_user_id_if_authenticated()
        user_id = "unknown" if user_id is None else str(user_id)
        return super(F,self).format(record) + ", user_id" + user_id
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could define [a custom filter](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-filters-to-impart-contextual-information) which injects a value for `record.user_id`. Done this way, you can define a format which includes `%(user_id)s` just like other (standard) record attributes:

```
format='%(asctime)-15s %(name)-5s %(levelname)-8s user_id %(user_id)-15s: %(message)s')
```

and then all logging calls will automatically add the `user_id` value.

---

```
import logging

class UserIDFilter(logging.Filter):
    """
    This is a filter which injects contextual information into the log.
    """
    from myapp.core import authenticationManager

    def filter(self, record):
        user_id = authenticationManager.current_user_id_if_authenticated()
        user_id = "unknown" if user_id is None else str(user_id)
        record.user_id = user_id
        return True


logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)-15s %(name)-5s %(levelname)-8s user_id %(user_id)-15s: %(message)s')

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
filt = UserIDFilter()
logger.addFilter(filt)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great, but should 1 be returned instead of True, as the docs prescribe : https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#filter-objects ?

Comment: Any object which evaluates to True in a boolean context will do. [The docs state](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.filter), "Applies this logger’s filters to the record and returns a true value if the record is to be processed". I prefer `True` over `1` here because it emphasizes that we're using the "boolean-ness" of the object.

Answer (score 3):

The [`logaugment`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/logaugment) ([Github page](https://github.com/svisser/logaugment)) package does this:

To use:

```
import logaugment

logaugment.set(logger, user_id='custom_value')
```

All logging calls with `logger` will now use the value `'custom_value'` for `%(user_id)s` in the logging message.

You can repeatedly call `logaugment.set` without problems to change the value. Alternatively, you can specify a callable that will be called every time when a logging call is made. This would allow dynamically computing / retrieving the user ID (see example in package README).

To install:

```
pip install logaugment
```

(disclaimer: I developed this package)

Comment: Great. Would it be possible for all the child loggers of the logger in your example, to use `custom_value` in their logging calls?